# How to debug a not starting up Cumulocity Microservice written in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, microservices, cumulocity

How to enable log for microservice developped in Python?

I can run hello-microservice without a glitch. However, my own microservice looks not starting up after I uploaded the zip file. I tried to wait for hours, and the same. I have run the docker locally without issue.

A call to any REST end point of the microservice returns,

```
{"error":"Microservice/Bad gateway","message":"Microservice not available Connection refused : Connection refused: a2c-microservice-scope-xxx-prod.svc.cluster.local/80","info":"https://www.cumulocity.com/guides/reference-guide/#error_reporting"}
```

I assume for some reason, the microservice I uploaded didn't start up properly. How can I enable any log to find out where goes wrong?

Comment: Turns out to be version of my instance is not new enough. Upgrade to new instance, now I can see the Logs button. @TyrManuZ was right, with the new version, Logs just show up by itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to logg to stdout and then you can access the logs through the user interface in Cumulocity IoT. It is available through the application UI in administration

[image: LogViewer Cumulocity IoT]

Here a python example how to configure the logging:

```
LOG_FORMATTER = logging.Formatter("%(asctime)s [%(threadName)-12.12s] [%(levelname)-5.5s]  %(message)s")

LOGGER = logging.getLogger()
LOGGER.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
CONSOLE_HANDLER = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
CONSOLE_HANDLER.setFormatter(LOG_FORMATTER)
LOGGER.addHandler(CONSOLE_HANDLER)
```

Comment: Good to know no special set up needed. I should have included that I did have logging and print both to console enabled, but no luck seeing the "Logs" button. I cleared cache of browser and no difference. My Cumolocity Version: 9.20.10 (backend), 9.20.10 (UI) wonder if same as yours.

Comment: Not sure but this logs not work always. Until today, I haven't understood them. Sometimes we saw them sometimes we didn't. What I have done for testing proposes is to send the logs, I want to get, as a response to the request. So, we are pretty sure what he microservice is doing. Hope this helps.

Comment: @Jorge Good information following which I enabled SMTPHandler to send out log. However, I did't receive any email so I assume the app doesn't run at all. As the docker image can run locally, I guess the issue is related to cumulocity.json. I played with postfix as "version": "1.0.0-SNAPSHOT", and still no luck.

Comment: @BillZhou Remember when you make changes on the microservices you need to change the version on the cumulocity.json. If that doesn't work try to delete the microservice and created again! I haven't tried the  SMTPHandler before so not sure how it works and can't help you with that, sorry.

Comment: @Jorge All good now after I migrate to a new version of the back-end instance. I also implement request and response to get log as you have advised which does look more straightforward. Cheers.